# Canon Powershot Lens Error

Tags: lens, error, powershot, troublehshooting

I have a Canon Powershot Camera SD1400 IS camera. It accidentally got dropped, and is now giving a Lens Error. :(

When I turn it on, it attempts to bring the lens out, but then retracts and says the following text:

> Lens Error
> Will shut down automatically 
> Restart Camera

In desperation, I looked at [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11755/what-should-i-do-about-canon-powershot-lens-error-restart-camera), and followed as many of the tips as possible. The only tip that gave any result was number 2, which says this:

> Try pressing and holding the Menu, Function, Function Set, or OK while turning on the camera, or otherwise find a "factory reset" option.

On my camera, I pressed the func button and the on button, and then got this screen:

[image]

For those who wonder what it is, it's just showing the time three minutes behind. When I press the left button on my camera, it changes the background color to the next color on the wheel. When I press right, it, again, changes the background color on the screen.

So what is going on here? Where is the factory reset button? Any help would be ***deeply*** appreciated, as this camera was a gift for me when I was 3. It wasn't even me who dropped it.

---

[Not a dupe](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11755/what-should-i-do-about-canon-powershot-lens-error-restart-camera). I explain why in the question body.

[Also not a dupe](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33936/what-to-do-when-my-camera-says-lens-error). My camera lens, as explained, doesn't stay outside. Instead, it tries to get out, but then retracts.

Comment: You dropped it, you broke it (the gearing is either cross-threaded or truly damaged). Next stop, the repair shop (if it's financially viable).

Comment: @Tetsujin can you explain what cross threaded means? also fwiw it wasnt me who dropped it.

Comment: The camera requires repair or replacement. From an economics standpoint, the cost of repair probably doesn’t make sense. From an emotional standpoint replacement is unsatisfactory. One option is to buy a working SD1400 (in the US, they appear to be available at modest cost) and use the working camera as a donor. Disassemble your camera and remove the lens assembly. Disassemble the donor and install its lens assembly in your camera. You will probably need JIS cross point screw drivers, not phillips. I recommend an iFixit toolkit from iFixit for such work.

Comment: I think it needs more than a click of a reset button. It obviously suffered physical damage. Try to be philosophical about it. It's just a cheap electronic device, and unfortunately, they all break eventually. The device itself shouldn't have the sentimental value, but rather the photos that were made with it - and you still have those. Keep it as a memento on your shelf and move on.

Comment: @osullic Thanks for the kind words. I'll go to the repair shop just in case it can be fixed, but if it can't, I have the sd card and all the photos.